# How to 'mount' a bitbake output build - 'wic.bz2' files

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, bitbake

Much like the ability to mount an image copy of an SD card, I am attempting to 'mount' a yocto/bitbake output file to inspect the contents or run via docker.

Looking through various docs/tutorial, it is stated the 'wic.bz2' file type is designed to burn straight to an sd card mount, surely this is not the only option?

Perhaps I'm mis-understand the result of bitbake build or indeed inspecting the wrong files?

Other info:
.I am using the 'Dunfell' branch to build a small Rasbperrypi3-64 image
.I am use WSL 20.04 V2

Sources:

[sdming updated to wic.bz2 format](https://github.com/agherzan/meta-raspberrypi/issues/637)

[Downloading and flashing to sd card](https://nxp.gitbook.io/8mmnavq/getting-started/quickstart/flash-sd-card-with-linux-image)

Comment: If it were a partition image, you could mount it as passthrough (after bunzip), but if it's a disk image with multiple partitions, I'm not sure that works.  Maybe this?  https://superuser.com/questions/211338/how-to-mount-a-multi-partition-disk-image-in-linux

Comment: @TimRoberts I did try booting it up using osfboot, I din't see anything. Good idea with bunzip, I'll give it a go thanks, I'm just amazed it isn't a common ask/tutorial, hence the question in perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @TimRoberts I post an answer to the question below however it was then deleted, unsure why as it includes your as stage one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't convert a wic file into an img file.
[As mentioned here](https://www.reddit.com/r/yocto/comments/qbr9gi/is_there_a_way_to_convert_a_wic_to_an_img/)

If you want to test the yocto output however, here is a guide:

1. As @Tim Robeerts mentioned, using [bunzip](https://www.javatpoint.com/linux-bzip2-bunzip2)
2. Either write the wic file to an sd card ([Example here](https://gist.github.com/govorox/ba187fd8d697248ca5a09a0b68c84ee9)), or other alternatives mentioned in [wic examples](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/dev-manual/wic.html#wic-examples)
3. Using a tool such as [rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/), create an .img file from the sd card.
4. Using [Quick EMUlator (QEMU)](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/qemu.html) Qemu emulator
   Allows you to boot the img file for testing.
   Alternatively, you can use virtual box:
   [Virtual box](https://roboticsbackend.com/install-raspbian-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-virtualbox/)

Answer (score 1):

Found two convenient ways to inspect a wic-file:

1. [`wic ls`](https://imxdev.gitlab.io/tutorial/How_to_inspect_OpenEmbedded_kickstart_wic_files/) ([docs](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/dev-manual/wic.html#using-wic-to-manipulate-an-image))

- Extract `image.wic.[gz|xz|bz2]` with the respective tool.
- `wic ls image.wic:3/usr/bin` - Show a path on the rootfs partition. Without `:3` and path it shows all available partitions.

2. Script

- [This script](https://gist.github.com/svagionitis/4781950458fce4d91993303783f7f0e0) creates a directory from the rootfs.
- Symbolic links are broken, but works well with `find` etc.
- In short, it decompresses, mounts to a loopback and copies the files to a specified directory.

Comment: Great info thanks! Such a shame there isn't a more direct way to spin it up and run without burning to a card.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The script is a very straight forward way to inspect the rootfs.
If you want the image running, you can try qemu, but probably won't work well unless you emulate the hardware correctly. I use wic and bmaptool to burn the image to hardware, takes like 2 mins, which is fine for my use cases.